# Loop values in a list in an elif

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the elif to work, I have tried allsorts and going a bit mad now.

Basically if guessed is not equal to an entry from randomwordslist then it should state it and not reduce guesses and not go to else statement.

error is "NameError: name 'word' is not defined"

Am I going about this all wrong?

```
while guess > 0:
    guessed = input("Guess ({} attempts left):".format(guess))
    guess = guess -1
    if guessed == answer:
        print("+++++  You have won  ++++++")
        break

    elif guessed != word in randomwordslist:
        print("Only words from above count as valid entries")
        continue

    else:
        match = 0
        for i in range(len(guessed)):
            if guessed[i].lower() == answer[i].lower():
                match += 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking Python to test two things:

```
guessed != word and word in randomwordslist
```

because Python comparisons are chained. But you *don't have `word` defined* which is why you get the exception.

Just test if `guessed` is not in `randomwordslist`:

```
if guessed not in randomwordslist:
```

if you wanted to verify that the string is not part of the list. `not in` is the opposite of `in`, the latter tests if a value *is* a member of the second operand.

If you don't want the number of guesses affected, move the test *up* so that you check it first:

```
while guess > 0:
    guessed = input("Guess ({} attempts left):".format(guess))

    if guessed not in randomwordslist:
        print("Only words from above count as valid entries")
        continue

    # valid guess, so it counts.
    guess = guess - 1

    if guessed == answer:
        print("+++++  You have won  ++++++")
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace your `elif` block by this one:

```
elif guessed not in randomwordslist:
    print("Only words from above count as valid entries")
    continue
```